# obj-c casting char * into char[]?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, char

i've seen the question asked for other languages, but not objective-c specifically. how would i cast char * into char []?

CODE:

```
NSString *thisString = @"48454C4C4F";
char *charString = [thisString UTF8String];

NSLog(@"%s",charString);

// output: 48454C4C4F

// how could i convert into char [] = {48,45,etc.)
```

Comment: Why char[]? Why not char*? If you pass char[] inside funtion it's the same char*. Could you show how you are going to use char[]?

Comment: yes, i show above in the comment `// how could i...`

Comment: Did I understood you right? You need convert hex-presendted string into byte array?

Comment: that is correct, currently the answer is converting the hex into ascii or something other than hex. i'm simply trying to convert the nsstring into 0x48, 0x45, etc. in a char[] array.

Comment: I would suggest use Base64 encoding. It's much shorter then HEX. And `NSData` have convinient functions to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSString *s = @"Some string";
const char *c = [s UTF8String];
```

You could also use

```
-[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]
```

if your string is encoded with something other than UTF-8.

Once you have the const char *, you can use it as an array of chars:

```
printf("%c\n", c[5]);
```

If you want to modify the string, make a copy:

```
char *cpy = strdup(c);
// Work with copy
free(cpy);
```

If you must have an actual char array you can do it like this:

```
NSString *data = @"Some string";
const char* utf8String = [data UTF8String];
size_t len = strlen(utf8String) + 1;

char mac [len];
memcpy(mac, utf8String, len);
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help.

Comment: it doesn't produce an array of char.

Comment: @user3256385 check my edited answer, does this answer your question?

Comment: @JohnWoods, I think he need get bytes from data presented in hex-encoded string.

Comment: ^ yes, that is exactly it.

Comment: `const char* utf8String = [data UTF8String];` hides instance variable `data`

Comment: @user3256385 You have `data` and another `data` as ivar, rename one of them.

Comment: okay, that works i think. one more question, if output to nslog is there a way to make it readable? currently `NSLog(@"mac: %c",mac);` produces `Ä` but if i do mac[0], etc. i can see it's the correct bytes, with the exception that they aren't grouped as bytes but single bits i guess?

Comment: meh, no big deal if it's too much. the important thing is that it converts, which it seems to, so thanks.

Comment: Wrong question - wrong answer. This is just yours string copied inside array.